# Check specific class in Beatiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting all accurences of a specific tag (td) with find_all() but I want to handle different classes.
My tags look something like this:

```
<td class="classname" colspan="2">
Something ...
</td>
```

I want to do different things depending on the classname.

I tried using has_attr() but it only seems to check if there is a single attribute present and does not work for whole expressions.

```
    for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
        if tag.has_attr("td", {"class": "search-detail-heading"}):
            Do Something()
        if tag.has_attr("td", {"class": "search-detail-subject"}):
            Do Something else()
```

Is there another method to check for this classname? Do I need to adjust find_all()? I kinda don't want to use find_all() for one classtype and then again for the next classtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `td` tag attributes information as a list using this code:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(list(tag.find("div").attrs.keys()))
```

Comment: That is nice. But it's not _tag.find()_. Only _tag.attrs.values()_ because I already found the tags with _find_all()_. Also I need the values not the keys haha. Thank you this is very helpful.

`for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(list(tag.attrs.values()))`

Comment: Oh ya my bad. I just copy and paste my code without reviewing it again. I'm so glad if that helps.